# W10 Task Bar Notification Area: determine active icons programmatically

Tags: notifications

you know the notification area in the Windows 10 task bar which shows some icons when clicking the little ^ symbol. I try to find a way to determine which icons are currently shown there - programmatically.

I found articles about NOTIFYICONDATA and Shell_NotifyIcon and stuff but this seems to be used to *create* icons only but does not allow to read out the notification area "content". Unfortunately I haven´t found any other APIs or specific events in the event history or something wich could be monitored.

Background is that some applications announce updates through an icon in that notification area. I would like to monitor that on a remote computer because I don´t want to logon there every day in order to check it manually.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It's unclear to me what your question is. Could you clarify your post?

Comment: There is an application running on a remote computer. This application checks for updates from time to time. If it detects an update to a newer version, it raises a notification in the notification area. If you logon to that computer and click the ^ symbol in the tray, you see the according icon there and can click it or manually open the according app in order to update it.

The issue is that I don´t want to logon to that remote PC. It shall tell me that this icon has appeared in the notification area in a different way. The application itself cannot do it.